# An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 26 of the file Error message: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 26 of the file Error
> message: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse
> time string ({field:launche_date_1623800874977}) at position 0 ({):
> Unexpected character

```php
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = get_field('event_date', false, false);
    $now = new DateTime();
    
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    

    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' old' : 'NA';
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: `{field:launche_date_1623800874977}` is not a valid value to instantiate `DateTime()`. Have a look at the [php manual for valid formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. Just relying on the Date/Time library to *guess* at the format of an arbitrary date string is a bad idea in any language. In PHP you'll want to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse according to a specific format.
2. That's not a guessable format, as @digijay has mentioned.
3. The problem with millisecond timestamps is that PHP's DateTime library will *always* consume the entire number and interpret it as seconds, no matter how much you fiddle with placeholders in the pattern.
4. Even a regular Unix timestamp in seconds is still not a guessable format for the DateTime constructor.

So, one way or another, you'll need to pre-parse that before it gets into the function you've posted.

Assuming you've finagled the timestamp out of your data structure:

```php
$timestamp_ms = 1623800874977;
$timestamp = intdiv($timestamp_ms, 1000);
```

There are two ways to convert from timestamp to DateTime:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
$dt = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

Now my preference would be to modify your existing function to accept a `DateTime` object rather than an arbitrary string, to accoutn for this and other 'unguessable' edge cases, in which case we'd be done for the day. But in case you have a lot of surrounding code that you can't really modify and you really want to kludge this in and pass in a properly "guessable" string:

```php
$date_string = $dt->format('c');
```

Where `c` is the ISO8601 format specifier, and ISO8601 is a format that is easily recognizable and won't be guessed wrong. Eg: `2021-06-15T23:47:54+00:00`